# How do I make a function use the altered version of a list in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to make a list with its elements representing the logic map given by

```
x_{n+1} = a*x_n(1-x_n)
```

I tried the following code (which adds stuff manually instead of a For loop):

```
x0 = Input["Enter x0"]
a = Input["a"]
M = {x0}
L[n_] := If[n < 1, x0, a*M[[n]]*(1 - M[[n]])]
Print[L[1]]
Append[M, L[1]]
Print[M]
Append[M, L[2]]
Print[M]
```

The output is as follows:

```
0.3
2
{0.3}
0.42
{0.3,0.42}
{0.3}
Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.3`} does not exist. >>
Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.3`} does not exist. >>
{0.3, 2 (1 - {0.3}[[2]]) {0.3}[[2]]}
{0.3}
```

It seems that, when the function definition is being called in Append[M,L[2]], L[2] is calling M[[2]] in the older definition of M, which clearly does not exist.

How can I make L use the newer, bigger version of M?

After doing this I could use a For loop to generate the entire list up to a certain index.

P.S. I apologise for the poor formatting but I could find out how to make Latex code work here.

Other minor question: What are the allowed names for functions and lists? Are underscores allowed in names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that, when the function definition is being called in
>   Append[M,L[2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html)], L[2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html) is calling M[[2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html)] in the older definition of M,
>   which clearly does not exist.
>
> How can I make L use the newer, bigger version of M?

`M` is never getting updated here. `Append` does *not* modify the parameters you pass to it; it returns the concatenated value of the arrays.

So, the following code:

```
A={1,2,3}
B=Append[A,5]
```

Will end up with `B={1,2,3,5}` and `A={1,2,3}`. `A` is not modfied.

To analyse your output,

```
0.3 // Output of x0 = Input["Enter x0"]. Note that the assignment operator returns the the assignment value.
2 // Output of a= Input["a"]
{0.3} // Output of M = {x0} 
0.42 // Output of Print[L[1]] 
{0.3,0.42} // Output of Append[M, L[1]]. This is the *return value*, not the new value of M 
{0.3} // Output of Print[M] 
Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.3`} does not exist. >> // M has only one element, so M[[2]] doesn't make sense 
Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.3`} does not exist. >> // ditto 
{0.3, 2 (1 - {0.3}[[2]]) {0.3}[[2]]} (* Output of Append[M, L[2]]. Again, *not* the new value of M *)
{0.3} // Output of Print[M]
```

---

The simple fix here is to use `M=Append[M, L[1]]`.

To do it in a single for loop:

```
xn=x0;
For[i = 0, i < n, i++,
  M = Append[M, xn];
  xn = A*xn (1 - xn)

];
```

A faster method would be to use `NestList[a*#*(1-#)&, x0,n]` as a variation of the method mentioned by Mark above.

Here, the expression `a*#*(1-#)&` is basically an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (`#` is its parameter, the `&` is a shorthand for enclosing it in `Function[]`). The [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html) method takes a function as one argument and recursively applies it starting with `x0`, for `n` iterations.

---

> Other minor question: What are the allowed names for functions and lists? Are underscores allowed in names?

No underscores, they're used for pattern matching. Otherwise a variable can contain alphabets and special characters (like theta and all), but no characters that have a meaning in mathematica (parentheses/braces/brackets, the at symbol, the hash symbol, an ampersand, a period, arithmetic symbols, underscores, etc). They may contain a dollar sign but *preferably* not start with one (these are usually reserved for system variables and all, though you can define a variable starting with a dollar sign without breaking anything).

Comment: I had read the documentation on Mathematica reference online. Here is the description: Append[expr, elem], gives expr with elem appended. I thought that it meant that Append appended 'elem' to 'expr'. Thanks for clearing up the confusion.

Comment: @varun If you're new to MMA, I suggest reading [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393), especially (in this case [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/435)). Mathematica is more oriented towards functional programming, recursion, and list iteration than for loops, so by default a function won't modify its parameters unless explicitly specified.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as if you are trying to compute the result of

```
FixedPointList[a*#*(1-#)&, x0]
```

Note:

1. Building lists element-by-element, whether you use a loop or some other construct, is almost always a bad idea in Mathematica. To use the system productively you need to learn some of the basic functional constructs, of which `FixedPointList` is one.
2. I'm not providing any explanation of the function I've used, nor of the interpretation of symbols such as `#` and `&`.  This is all covered in the documentation which explains matters better than I can and with which you ought to become familiar.
3. Mathematica allows alphanumeric (only) names and they must start with a letter.  Of course, Mathematic recognises many Unicode characters other than the 26 letters in the English alphabet as alphabetic. By convention (only) intrinsic names start with an upper-case letter and your own with a lower-case.
4. The underscore is most definitely not allowed in Mathematica names, it has a specific and widely-used interpretation as a short form of the `Blank` symbol.

Oh, LaTeX formatting doesn't work hereabouts, but Mathematica code is plenty readable enough.

Comment: Oh, the FixedPointsList function is quite useful. However, I wanted to use this algorithm/idea and extend it to cases where the final answer is not a fixed point. For eg. in the region 3<a<4, the logic map does not converge to one point but there exist multiple subsequences converging to different limits. After the certain value of a, the logic map is totally aperiodic. So I do not think that I could use FixedPointList in that case. I apologise for not mentioning this in the question.

Comment: So look at `Fold`, `Nest`, `Map`,  *etc*.